# не могу получить ответ от метода messages.send

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

мне нужно отправить сообщение и после получить id данного сообщение но как не пытался не получается

```
def sms():
    t = input("token: ")
    y = input("ваше сообщение: ")
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=t)
    vk = vk_session.get_api()
    u = vk.friends.get(order='name', count=5000, fields='name')
    for i in u["items"]:
        k = i['id']
        vk.messages.send(user_id=k, dont_parse_links=0, message=y, random_id=k)
        z = {'response'}
        print(z)
```

ответ выглядит так

```
{
"response": 22937
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте:

```
response = vk.messages.send(user_id=k, dont_parse_links=0, message=y, random_id=k)
print(response)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/vis/mini_tool-vk.py", line 105, in <module>
    vibor()
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/vis/mini_tool-vk.py", line 100, in vibor
    sms()
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/vis/mini_tool-vk.py", line 82, in sms
    print(g['response'])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: поменял только имя переменной

Comment: Значит, просто `print(g)`